# java.util.zip.ZipException: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: java, jar

I have a jar file that I have written, which basically converts a tab delimited text file to a specified XML format. It was written in eclipse and runs fine from the command line on windows 7.

I've been running it using the following command:

```
java -jar convert.jar [filename]
```

Java version is 1.6.0_21

Now I also tried to run this jar on Windows XP running Java version 1.6.0_37, and it worked fine.

However, on a third computer running Windows XP, the following exception occurs when running the above command

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: The system
cannot find the file specified
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:112)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:117)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:55)
```

I am also unable to run the jar without command line arguments. In this case I believe a NoClassDefFound was thrown.

```
echo %CLASSPATH%
```

gives

```
.;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip
```

Any ideas on what is happening here? I would guess that something is wrong with the environment variables on this third computer, but I am not sure exactly what it is. Thanks in advance.

The MANIFEST.MF file looks like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .
Main-Class: Convert
```

Comment: What does the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file inside the jar file look like?

Comment: http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalID=Q107323 look here, they discribed problems like yours

Comment: Does the file exists at the location you provided as argument? are there spaces in the filepath?

Comment: I updated my original question with the Manifest.mf file. The command line argument (the file name) does exist at the location provided. There are spaces in the filepath, but this wasn't an issue on the other Windows XP computer, so I guess I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: Since you manually performed this in three places, and it worked fine in two of them, is it possible you made a mistake and tried to execute it from the wrong directory the third time?

Comment: I mean, I can go check again but that was also the first thing I thought of. If that is the issue, would it even throw a different exception when trying to run the jar with a command line argument as opposed to just running it without the command line argument?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?